# Elmah on asp .net Webforms generating HTTP 500.19 error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, elmah

I've got an error on an a server running elmah.  I have some security entries that need to be set in the web.config.  One of them is a customHeaders entry.

The config error is:
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'X-Frame-Options'

I am guessing that I since I already have the entry, Elmah generates an internal error by trying to add the entry into the in memory copy of the web.config.  Is there any way around this issue?

TIA.

Comment: ELMAH doesn't add any security attributes. Could you share your entire web.config file?

Comment: actually, I think you triggered something in my head.  I found I had created two X-Frame-Options.  Taking the wrong one out fixed it.  Thanks @ThomasArdal.